# How to add decimal values in Bash

Tags: bash

How to increment the value of the string `test_1.0` to `test_1.1` in Bash

I have a counter variable and wanted to increase the decimal value by 1 every time, when I run the script.

I tried this but it failed saying

```
 counter=1
 k=test_1.0
 k=$((echo $k + $counter| bc))

-bash: echo monitor_1.0 + 1| bc: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0 + 1| bc")
```

Comment: The error message would say `echo test_1.0 + 1| bc: syntax error` but I suppose we can guess what you mean. For consistency, you should probably [edit] to clarify what you want. There are also problems with your arithmetic; 1.0 + 1 adds to 2.0, not 1.1.

Comment: `$((....))` does not make sense here. This imposed integer context (for instance for calculation) into the content, but first of all, you have here numbers with a decimal point, and then, you are already using `bc` for  the calculation. What's the point in applying a bash integer context? Finally, your variable `k` does not hold a number. BTW, if you would zsh, you could do float arithmetic directly in the shell, but of course your variable `k` would still be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing arithmetic expansion `$((...))` with command substitution `$(...)` syntax.

```
k=$(echo $k + $counter | bc)
```

is the proper way to feed the output of `echo` into `bc` and capture its output in the variable `k`.

However, of course, in your example, `k` is not a valid float. You would have to extract the number into a separate variable, or (perhaps better) omit the `test_` prefix from `k` itself, and only add it when you need to print the full string.

A minimal fix is to just trim it and add it back when performing the increment.

```
k=test_$(echo ${k#test_} + $counter | bc)
```

Bash by itself only supports integer arithmetic. If `$k` and `$counter` were integers, you could simply say

```
k=$((k + counter))
```

or even

```
((k+=counter))
```

Your example asks about incrementing by 0.1 but your numbers add up to 2.0 so probably you need to adjust something somewhere. Should the value of `counter` be divided by 10, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "test_1.0" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $1"_"$2+1"."$3+1}'
test_2.1
$ echo "test_1.9" | awk -F_ -v counter=0.1 '{printf $1"_";printf "%.1f\n",$2+counter}'
test_2.0
```

Comment: `echo "test_1.9" | awk -F_ -v counter=0.1 '{print $1"_"$2+counter}'` :::::::::::::::::::: ————>
`test_2`

Answer (score 1):

Bash can't do floating point math but `awk` can and it's quite convenient check this example:

```
k=test_1.0 # here _ is a separator between name and version lets use it

$ awk -F_ '{name=$1; version=$2; increment=$3}END{printf("%s_%.1f", name, version+increment)}' <<< "$k"'_0.7'
test_1.7

$ awk -F_ '{name=$1; version=$2; increment=$3}END{printf("%s_%.1f", name, version+increment)}' <<< "$k"'_1'
test_2.0

$ awk -F_ '{name=$1; version=$2; increment=$3}END{printf("%s_%.1f", name, version+increment)}' <<< "$k"'_3.5'
test_4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash arithmetic expansion (the `$((...))` construct):

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0
printf -v k 'test_1.%d' $((++counter))
echo "$k"
printf -v k 'test_1.%d' $((++counter))
echo "$k"
```

Comment: This will increment from `test_1.9` to `test_1.10`, not `test_2.0`. We can only speculate about which of the two the OP really wants. From their asking about how to do it arithmetically, I'm guessing the latter.

Comment: @tripleee The OP could have stated that the value was intended to be increased by `0.1`, in that case.